# Vaadin Binder for MultiSelectComboBox

Tags: java, binding, vaadin, vaadin-flow, incompatibility

Can somebody please help me with Vaadin Binder for this `MultiSelectComboBox`. 
Does the MultiSelectComboBox component, always requires a `Set` for the binding methods ?

I have such entity

```
@Entity(name = "recipes")
public class Recipe {

    // ...

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Category> categories;

    // ...
}
```

My implementation of Binder for MultiSelectComboBox

```
private final Binder<Recipe> binder = new Binder<>(Recipe.class);
private final MultiSelectComboBox<Category> categoryMultiselect = new MultiSelectComboBox<>("Categories");

// ...

private void initBinder() {
    binder.forField(categoryMultiselect)
            .asRequired("Please fill this field")
            .withValidator(s -> !s.isEmpty(), "Please select at least one category")
            .withValidator(s -> s.size() <= 5, "Please select up to 5 categories")
            .bind(Recipe::getCategories, Recipe::setCategories);
}
```

Throws `Incompatible types: Set<Category> is not convertible to List<Category>`, as MultiSelectComboBox returns a `Set` and `Recipe::getCategories` returns a `List<Category>`.

Any ideas how can be this avoided ? 
**PS:** I don't really want to change the `List<Category>` to `Set<Category>` in my `Recipe.class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert Set to list using withConverter.

```
private void initBinder() {
Converter<Set<Category>, List<Category>> setToListConverter = new Converter<Set<Category>, List<Category>>() {
    @Override
    public Result<List<Category>> convertToModel(Set<Category> set, ValueContext context) {
        List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
        return Result.ok(list);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Category> convertToPresentation(List<Category> list, ValueContext context) {
        Set<Category> set = new HashSet<>(list);
        return set;
    }
};

binder.forField(categoryMultiselect)
        .asRequired("Please fill this field")
        .withValidator(s -> !s.isEmpty(), "Please select at least one category")
        .withValidator(s -> s.size() <= 5, "Please select up to 5 categories")
        .withConverter(setToListConverter)
        .bind(Recipe::getCategories, Recipe::setCategories);}
```

(https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/binding-data/components-binder-validation#converting-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it always needs a `Set`, as this is part of its signature.  This
implies, that the items to select are unique to the selection, and they
are unordered - both things, that a `List` can not promise -- whether
this is actually important for the use-case is not clear.

So either switch to another component, that allows for ordering and
duplicates -- or adopt between the `Set` and the `List` in your UI data
class or in the binder (make sure your category is a good citizen for
a `Set` (give it equals and hash-code) and deal with the order for your
`List` by some means (e.g. add a priority to the category)).

Comment: The main purpose why I don't want to have `Set` instead of `List`, is because Java didn't add a method `get(index)` for `Set` collection. I have used a lot of getting by index method, and I don't really like any handmade implementations using `stream()` for this.